# Type Conversion Errors with DateTime

Tags: sql, vba, datetime, adodb, type-conversion

I am trying to add data to a SQL database column which called 'ModifiedDate' and is of type 'DateTime', using the following code:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim dteModifiedDate As Date
Dim cm As ADODB.Command
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set cm = New ADODB.Command
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cn.ConnectionString = strDBConnectionString
cn.Open

Set cm.ActiveConnection = cn

dteModifiedDate = fso.GetFile("C:\TestFile.txt").DateLastModified

cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("@ModifiedDate", adDBDate, adParamInput, , dteModifiedDate)

cm.CommandText = "SELECT CAST('@ModifiedDate' as DateTime) FROM MainData"
cm.CommandType = adCmdText

cm.Execute
```

The problem is that when I run this, the code breaks on the execute statement with this error:

```
Run-time error -2147217913 (80040e07)
conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have tried several different 'Type's for the command (adDate,adDBTimestamp,adWChar etc...) but get errors regarding conversion between data types.

What data type do you use for this?  Obviously I need to be able to get the parameter data type correct with a type that is compatible with the SQL table data type.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the length of the date. Also `adDate` should be fine:

```
cm.Parameters.Append cm.CreateParameter("@ModifiedDate", adDate, adParamInput, , dteModifiedDate)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I changed as suggested however it didn't fix the issue so i've updated the original post with more details and the new error.

Comment: Add a watch to `dteModifiedDate`, what is assigned to the variable when it gets assigned?

Comment: It gets assigned '18/02/2015 16:48:44' as Date type

Comment: Just to check, you have tried using `adDate` without the length parameter specified?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with the adDate parameter without length :)

Comment: I'm not sure then in which case. The only other thing I can thing of is try to define `dteModifiedDate` as a string and use it with `adDate`. It should be automatically converted. Worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Seems like it doesn't like the conversion between the two data types but, I think if I remove dteModifiedDate from a parameter and just build the string, it should work....perhaps!!